# Windows form is not saving

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics

I am getting following error, while I try to save a Windows form on Visual Studio 2012. All the other forms are OK. Only a particular form pops out the error.

And, once I double click on a control of that form it won't take me to code view.

[image]

Comment: are you using any custom control?

Comment: The error says you need to mark your `clsTask` class, which you added to the `TaskList` in the designer, as `[Serializable]`...

Comment: yea I am using  a user control.

Comment: My class is marked as follows 
[Serializable]
public class clsTask
{
}

Comment: [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public List<clsTask> TaskList 
        {
            get
            {
                return _TaskList;
            }
            set
            {
                _TaskList = value;
            }
        }
```